# XMonad shift multiple workspaces over

Tags: xmonad

I am a proud and satisfied user of XMonad, but I don't really know how to write configs for it. I was wondering whether it was possible to customize my xmonad.hs config to achieve the following functionality:

When focused on an empty workspace, enter a certain modifier (e.g. alt-shift-left) to move all following (i.e. higher index) workspaces to the left by one. So, if I have a terminal in workspace 1, a browser in workspace 3, and email in workspace 4, I can switch to workspace 2 and use this keystroke to move the browser to workspace 2 and the mail client to workspace 3.

When focused on any workspace, enter a certain modifier (e.g. alt-shift-right) to move all the windows in that workspace to the next workspace to the right, shifting all the following indices over by one as well, Hilbert Hotel style. That way, if I want to open a window in the second workspace, I can empty it by moving its current contents to the third, the contents of the third to the fourth, and so on. Essentially, this is the inverse of the above operation.

XMonad seems powerful and customizable enough that I doubt that this is impossible. Does anyone have an implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`XMonad.Actions.DynamicWorkspace`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-DynamicWorkspaces.html) you can add and delete Workspaces, and [`XMonad.Actions.WorkspaceNames`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-WorkspaceNames.html) provides functionality for renaming them.

This way you can

- delete the current workspace and rename the ones to the right by -1 and
- add a workspace and rename the ones to the right by +1.

This way there is no need to shift the applications.

Comment: This looks useful. Would it be too much to ask for an implementation? I haven't really gotten to monads in Haskell yet and XMonad is a bit arcane to me. Thanks!